# git android studio push ignored filees

Tags: git, android-studio

I have this ignore  file , but it does not work , every time we commit and cached file is pushed

```
# Built application files
*.apk
*.aar
*.ap_
*.aab

# Files for the ART/Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/
out/
#  Uncomment the following line in case you need and you don't have the release build type files in your app
# release/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/
```

**strong text**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaZ9J.png

Comment: I did not see any file on `.gitignore` being selected in you screenshot. `.bin`, `.lock` and `.xml` are not in you `.gitgnore`, can you elaborate?

Comment: Oh, I just saw `.gradle`, but was that added BEFORE you added the `.gitignore`?

Comment: yes , I also try to delete git and add files again